# Blur ImageView using IBDesignable

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ibdesignable

Can a VisualEffect (Blur) be added to a UIImageView using a IBDesignable class? (I've search all over and found nothing so far) I've tried adding it a layer.addSublayer(layer: CALayer) but there is not CALayer for visual effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making a subclass of UIImageView like the following:

```
@IBDesignable
class Blur: UIImageView {

    @IBInspectable var blurImage:UIImage?{
        didSet{
            updateImage(blurImage!)
        }
    }


    func updateImage(imageBlur:UIImage){
        let imageToBlur:CIImage = CIImage(image: imageBlur)!
        let blurFilter:CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
        blurFilter.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: "inputImage")
        let resultImage:CIImage = blurFilter.valueForKey("outputImage")! as! CIImage
        self.image = UIImage(CIImage: resultImage)
    }



    }
```

You will have to play around with it to get it the way you want.

More information about `CoreImageFilter` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIGaussianBlur)

Comment: You can say something like         blurFilter.setValue(5, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)